# Realm slow with updating managed object's field

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a fairly simple managed Realm object `RealmAlertItem` consisting of a few Strings and floats. I have a function `showAlertNotification()` which gets called subsequently (triggered from outside from the network) and it relies on the fact that previous execution is fully done before the next call. In this function I just change one float field (see `setHigh()` and `setLow()` below). If both are 0, I delete the object.

However, it seems Realm can't update the object in time and on 2nd call of the function, the object still has old `high` and `low` values.

Here is logcat:

```
08:47:04.180 D/debug: showAlertNotification(), guid: 58dfe381-b615-4ce0-beaf-5abb9b0733ac
08:47:04.185 D/debug: high 10000.0 , low 10800.0
08:47:04.205 D/debug: b // here we call RealmInstance.getThreadRealm().executeTransaction(realm1 -> alert.setHigh(0));
08:47:04.214 /debug: showAlertNotification(), guid: 58dfe381-b615-4ce0-beaf-5abb9b0733ac
08:47:04.215 /debug: high 10000.0 , low 10800.0 // here high should be 0!
08:47:04.224 /debug: d
```

As you can see the second invocation happens very fast after the 1st one (about 30ms later).

Here is code:

```
private void showAlertNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, String coinSlug, String coinName, Bitmap logo) {
    Log.d("debug", "showAlertNotification(), guid: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("guid"));

    RealmAlertItem alert = RealmInstance.getThreadRealm().where(RealmAlertItem.class).equalTo("guid", remoteMessage.getData().get("guid")).findFirst();
    if(alert == null)
        return;


    ... some work


    // disable/delete this alert
    if(!alert.isRepeating()) {
        if (isHighLimit) {
            if (alert.getLow() == 0) {
                Log.d("debug", "a");
                RealmInstance.getThreadRealm().executeTransaction(realm1 -> alert.deleteFromRealm());
            } else {
                Log.d("debug", "b");
                RealmInstance.getThreadRealm().executeTransaction(realm1 -> alert.setHigh(0));
            }
        } else {
            if (alert.getHigh() == 0) {
                Log.d("debug", "c");
                RealmInstance.getThreadRealm().executeTransaction(realm1 -> alert.deleteFromRealm());
            } else {
                Log.d("debug", "d");
                RealmInstance.getThreadRealm().executeTransaction(realm1 -> alert.setLow(0));
            }
        }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent("notifyAlertsChanged");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainApplication.getAppContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

If needed, here is my RealmInstance Singleton:

```
public class RealmInstance {
    private Realm realm;
    private static RealmInstance realmInstance;

    public static RealmInstance getInstance() {
        if (realmInstance == null) {
            realmInstance = new RealmInstance();
        }
        return realmInstance;
    }

    private RealmInstance() {
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        } catch (IllegalStateException err) {
            init(MainApplication.getAppContext());
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {
        return realm;
    }

    public static Realm getThreadRealm() {
        return Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        Realm.init(context);

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                .Builder()
                .schemaVersion(13)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: where does come from the log line `08:47:04.185 D/debug: high 10000.0 , low 10800.0`, I don't see the corresponding `Log.d`. If you debug it step by step, do you see the problem ? Aside, I wonder why you use a RealmInstance singleton, you should init your Realm in your Application class. And are you closing realm everytime you use an instance of it ?

Comment: @Maelig, it seems I was misusing Realm with the singleton as I never closed Realm :O I am now rewriting the code and removing the singleton class altogether.

Comment: Good thing to refact that, you would have performances issues later :/ Does it solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it works much better now! Thanks for your input.

Comment: I posted an answer to help anyone coming around here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init your Realm configuration in your `Application.java`, and call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` when you need it (i.e get rid of your singleton class).

You also need to close realm instances after you used it, or you get side effects like you are experimenting and later you'll have performance issues.